# Examples of functions where the set of discontinuities is not open or closed

Tags: continuity

I have examples where the set of discontinuities is $\mathbb{Q}$, so is neither open or closed.  But are there other examples? I haven't found more.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You already *know* that it isn't open or closed.  What sort of answer are you expecting?  Have you looked at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#The_set_of_discontinuities_of_a_function)?

Comment: I wanted to know if there are other examples not with an open and closed set of discontinuities at the same time

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I suggest you edit the title of the equation to something like "Examples of functions where the set of discontinuities is not open or closed".

Comment: If you wish to ask about "other examples", you should clarify what examples (of functions) you know about, and perhaps sharpen the Question to indicate whether other functions with set of discontinuities $\mathbb{Q}$ are of interest.

Comment: The set of discontinuities of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is always an $F_\sigma$ set (countable union of closed sets), and every $F_\sigma$ subset of $\mathbb R$ is the set of discontinuities of some function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R.$

Comment: For a precise characterization (which I notice @bof posted while I was hunting down a reference), see the mathoverflow question [Find a continuous function with a prescribed continuity set](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132801/find-a-continuous-function-with-a-prescribed-continuity-set).